# What do these release tags mean on a github commit page?

Tags: github, tags

I wanted to check the earliest release tag associated with a commit on github but I dont know what do these tags actually mean on the commit description page?

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags listed there are the tags which contain this commit.  The latest one is on the left.  This is so that people can tell what versions a commit that fixed their problem is included in.  This can be determined with a clone of the repository, but this is simpler than performing a full clone for that purpose.

In this case, it probably means that the commit was first included in 2.13.0.

Comment: I also think this might be true, but with all future releases will this space simply list all those tags for this commit?

Comment: They will continue to be listed and there's an ellipsis button for expansion if the list gets too large.